# Jest mock the window.open

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

How I can mock the window.open with jest?
I tried several options but each of them is failed

I need to check if the window.open is called and it should be called with certain params

Assume that I have something like this

```
open(): void {
  window.open('/link');
}
```

Comment: Please consider options that you tried and what issues have you faced.

Comment: `Error: Not implemented: window.open ` or `Error: Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function`

Answer (score 1):

Install these packages:

```
jest-environment-jsdom
jest-environment-jsdom-global
```

Add `"testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-global"` in your jest configurations.

Suppose you have a function like this:

```js
open() {
  window.open("abc");
}
```

Then inside test file:

```js
it("should open the url in window", () => {
  const openSpy =  jest.spyOn(window, "open");

  open();

  expect(openSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(openSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("abc");
});
```

Comment: It will not work, your tests is running with node and you don't have any `window` there

Comment: Added the configurations that you need to add to make it working.